# Лексические ошибки и их классификация

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

ПОМОГИТЕ ПЛИЗ

1. Нельзя нарушать существующий в природе баланс.
   СПАСИБО

Comment: Предложите свои варианты ответов.

Comment: Марина, а почему мы должны (да еще и в приказной форме) выполнять твою домашку? Сама-то хоть что сделала?

Comment: ... хотя бы укажите на место дефектов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нельзя нарушать существующий в природе баланс (нарушить можно баланс; дисбаланс — уже нарушение).
2. Встретимся около 17 часов (район может быть, например, Бутово, но не время).
3. В этом тексте много ошибок (дефект можеть быть у вещи, поломка, например; или болезнь может быть у человека, но не в тексте).
4. Фирма предлагает товары в большом ассортименте и по самым низким ценам. (Дешевый — это уже цена. Товары чьи? Ассортимента? Это неправильно.)
5. Эта видеотехника — просто хит этого года (бестселлер — к литературе, а не к технике).
6. Пресса высоко оценивает результаты выборов (отзыв может быть позитивным, а оценка — высокой).
7. К сведению подписчиков газет и журналов (подписчики — уже получатели, тут тавтология).
8. Он, тогда еще неизвестный летчик, хотел полететь в космос (опять тавтология: тогда еще неизвестный или доселе неизвестный).
9. Эта статья поразила меня до глубины души (можно поразить до глубины души или удивить).

Comment: Здесь не выполняют ДЗ, это не формальное правило. Оно для понимающих. Нельзя нарушать существующий в природе баланс.

Comment: @shampar не знал, спасибо что сообщили, больше не буду )

Comment: Рад стараться...